# Dapper maps object using second ID column rather than first

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

My SQL query returns employee information which I map with dapper.  The SQL returns the PK from the Employee table, along with various other columns, then the PK of each child object with their columns.  But the first object, an EmployeeModel, receives the PK of the first child object.  I've tried reordering the SQL query without success.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the Dapper syntax?

```
var sql = @"SELECT e.id, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Nickname, 
                                    em.id, em.Address, em.Type, 
                                    jt.id, jt.Name, 
                                    p.id, p.Number, p.Type,
                                    d.id, d.Name,
                                    es.id, es.Name
                                   

                          FROM dbo.Employees e 
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.Emails em
                          ON em.EmployeeID = e.id
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.JobTitles jt                           
                          ON e.JobTitleID = jt.id
                          LEFT JOIN Phones p
                          ON p.EmployeeID = e.id
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.Departments d
                          ON e.DepartmentID = d.id
                          LEFT JOIN dbo.EmployeeStatus es  
                          ON e.StatusID = es.id";

                var employees = await connection.QueryAsync<EmployeeModel,
                                                            EmailModel,
                                                            TitleModel,
                                                            PhoneModel,
                                                            DepartmentModel,
                                                            EmployeeModel>
                                                            (sql, (e, em, t, p, d) =>
                {
                    e.EmailList.Add(em);
                    e.JobTitle = t;
                    e.Department = d;
                    e.PhoneList.Add(p);
                    return e;
                },
                splitOn: "id, id, id, id, id");
```

Here's the SQL result.  The first EmployeeModel, for instance, ends up with ID = 2 instead of 9, and so on.  (The user info is fictional.)

```
9   Abed    Nadir   Abed    2   Abed.Nadir@Greendale.com    Campus  9   Human Resources Manager 4   555-212-1345    Home    2   Sales   1   Active
9   Abed    Nadir   Abed    2   Abed.Nadir@Greendale.com    Campus  9   Human Resources Manager 13  555-224-7894    Work    2   Sales   1   Active
9   Abed    Nadir   Abed    6   Abed.Nadir@Gmail.com    Personal    9   Human Resources Manager 4   555-212-1345    Home    2   Sales   1   Active
9   Abed    Nadir   Abed    6   Abed.Nadir@Gmail.com    Personal    9   Human Resources Manager 13  555-224-7894    Work    2   Sales   1   Active
9   Abed    Nadir   Abed    7   Abed.Nadir@Yahoo.com    Personal    9   Human Resources Manager 4   555-212-1345    Home    2   Sales   1   Active
9   Abed    Nadir   Abed    7   Abed.Nadir@Yahoo.com    Personal    9   Human Resources Manager 13  555-224-7894    Work    2   Sales   1   Active
10  Jeffrey Winger  Winger  1   Jeff.Winger@Greendale.com   Campus  3   Machinist   5   555-212-4567    Home    3   Manufacturing   4   Suspended
10  Jeffrey Winger  Winger  1   Jeff.Winger@Greendale.com   Campus  3   Machinist   6   555-207-5432    Work    3   Manufacturing   4   Suspended
10  Jeffrey Winger  Winger  1   Jeff.Winger@Greendale.com   Campus  3   Machinist   7   555-207-2145    Cell    3   Manufacturing   4   Suspended
10  Jeffrey Winger  Winger  3   JeffWinger@HHH.com  Work    3   Machinist   5   555-212-4567    Home    3   Manufacturing   4   Suspended
10  Jeffrey Winger  Winger  3   JeffWinger@HHH.com  Work    3   Machinist   6   555-207-5432    Work    3   Manufacturing   4   Suspended
10  Jeffrey Winger  Winger  3   JeffWinger@HHH.com  Work    3   Machinist   7   555-207-2145    Cell    3   Manufacturing   4   Suspended
11  Annie   Edison  Annie   4   Annie.Edison@Greendale.com  Campus  3   Machinist   8   555-225-3754    Cell    5   Receiving   1   Active
13  Pierce  Hawthorn    Pierce  5   Pierce.Hawthorn@Greendale.com   Campus  9   Human Resources Manager 10  555-225-3525    Home    6   Finance 5   Sabbatical
14  Shirley Bennett Shirley 1006    Shirley.Bennett@Greendale.com   Campus  8   Accounts Payable Clerk  14  555-555-6792    Home    8   Equipment   4   Suspended
14  Shirley Bennett Shirley 1007    JesusLovesMe@TrueFaith.com  Personal    8   Accounts Payable Clerk  14  555-555-6792    Home    8   Equipment   4   Suspended
15  Troy    Barnes  Troy    1008    Troy.Barnes@Greendale.com   Campus  9   Human Resources Manager 15  555-229-2855    Cell    2   Sales   2   Former
15  Troy    Barnes  Troy    1009    ButterflyInTheSky@Gmail.com Personal    9   Human Resources Manager 15  555-229-2855    Cell    2   Sales   2   Former
```

Comment: Well you have multiple columns named `id` what do you expect? It's not a mind reader. Give each column a unique name. You are correct that the first object needs no split column

Comment: Ah.  I expected it to see them and treat them sequentially.  But if that's not how it works, cool.

Comment: If all Id columns are named the same, you only have to specify it once. And: The default for the splitOn parameter is "Id", so you don't have to specify it at all.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but it seems the two answers here contradict one another.  Charlieface says each column needs a unique name, whereas @Palle Due seems to be saying they don't have to be unique.  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: If you look at the very first multi maping test [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/cdc63c747e74ca86bfe937524d406e6eb6882f3f/tests/Dapper.Tests/MultiMapTests.cs), you will see that there are two Id columns and no splitOn parameter.

Comment: I know this old but came across this today. I think the problem must lie in your SplitOn param being "id, id, id, id, id".  If all of your tables have a PK named "id" then you would only specify id once i.e. splitOn: "id". Dapper then uses this to create & populate a new object based on the order of your classes defined in the QueryAsync function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var sql = @"SELECT e.id, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.Nickname, 
                                em.id as em_id, em.Address as em_Address, em.Type as em_Type, 
                                jt.id as jt_id, jt.Name as jt_Name, 
                                p.id as p_id, p.Number as p_Number, p.Type as p_Type,
                                d.id as d_id, d.Name as d_Name,
                                es.id as es_id, es.Name as es_Name
                               

                      FROM dbo.Employees e 
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.Emails em
                      ON em.EmployeeID = e.id
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.JobTitles jt                           
                      ON e.JobTitleID = jt.id
                      LEFT JOIN Phones p
                      ON p.EmployeeID = e.id
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.Departments d
                      ON e.DepartmentID = d.id
                      LEFT JOIN dbo.EmployeeStatus es  
                      ON e.StatusID = es.id";

            var employees = await connection.QueryAsync<EmployeeModel,
                                                        EmailModel,
                                                        TitleModel,
                                                        PhoneModel,
                                                        DepartmentModel,
                                                        EmployeeModel>
                                                        (sql, (e, em, t, p, d) =>
            {
                e.EmailList.Add(em);
                e.JobTitle = t;
                e.PhoneList.Add(p);
                e.Department = d;
                return e;
            },
            splitOn: "em_id, jt_id, p_id, d_id");
```

Comment: This worked, except I only put the "as" modifiers on the id column.